# Spontaneous modification of values in C array

Tags: c, arrays, methods, parameter-passing

I have a weird problem. I have a while cycle where I fill an array by values (in CDC_Receive_HS method). After that I pass this array as a parameter to method for processing. But when I look at values which contains passed array in that method, they are different in comparison with values which have been loaded to it. Am I doing something wrong?

```
uint8_t* buffer; 
int counter;

static int8_t CDC_Init_HS(void)
{
  ....

  buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 500000);
  counter = 0;

  ....
}   

static int8_t CDC_Receive_HS (uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
    while(counter < 20000)
    {
        int i = 0;

        for(; i<*Len; i++)
        {
            buffer[counter++] = Buf[i];
        }
        USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(hUsbDevice_1);
        return (USBD_OK);
    }
  //here are values in "buffer" array ok, so pass it to ParseCommand method
    ParseCommand(buffer, counter);
    return (USBD_OK); 
}

static void ParseCommand (uint8_t* Data, uint32_t Len)
{
  Data[0];
  Data[1];
  ... processing ...
  //Here are values in "Data" array different
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Smells like buffer overflow.

Comment: But in "buffer" array there are only 20 064 values added and the size of this array is 500 000, if I am right.

Comment: I guess it is a typo but to be sure: into ParseCommand mean you `Data[0]` instead of `Buf[0]`?

Comment: Is `int` 32 bits on your platform?

Comment: Are the values already different right at the entry of `ParseCommand` ? If yes then the call to `USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket` might have messed up the values in `buffer`. If not then  `... processing ...` is most likely messing up buffer.

Comment: to LPs: Yes, you are right it is typo, sorry for that. Int is 32bit on my platform.

Comment: to Michael Walz: Yes they are already different at the entry. I have verified that values right above the ParseCommand calling and the were ok.

Comment: @Shadow2334 then the problem is in `USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket`. BTW dont write _to Username_ in comments, but write _@Username_, then Username will get notified by stackoverflow.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for advice, I am new here :-). I just found where the problem is! The size of alocated array is too big - if I change it to 50 000, it works.

Comment: @Shadow2334 beware, if the buffer is too big, it would just waste memory, but it should work anyway. If I were you I'd double check if there is something else going on and you're not stumbling over undefined behaviour.